# Express.js error default engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It all worked fine until I did not change View folder in the root into view with small capital letter.

the structure of folder is

```
server
app
View
index.html
```

before this I was getting error about no default engine was specified, because I deleted express generator middleware for using jade, but it worked.. Now if I rename View into view, CPU on my computer goes 100%, and terminal just throws same mistake about default engine but infinitely...Does express generator automatically searc for index file in view folder?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your app.js file.

Comment: app.js on server https://repl.it/C4sN

Comment: looks like you have not setup view engine below the comment `// view engine setup

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');` ?

Comment: You need to add these 2 statements in your app.js file.

Comment: I added it, it doesn't show error anymore but it is all the same the app is unusable, my PC CPU hits 100%, and in terminal it is just hitting the same endpoint every milisecond https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/574d9b38b745641bf213815d/1301x762/01059d1062113594362cb4617e847c59/Selection_054.png

Comment: Do you have that main.html file in your Views folder? And have you added the statements I asked for with a capital V in views?

Comment: yeah, i added with View but all it gets is throw an error every milisecond.. yes I have but also have index.html in the folder above

Comment: somehow i menage to make it work...the problem was Angular making request to old View folder in ui router templateUrl part

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it :)